# Beam GroupByKey in Spark Streaming on Yarn

Tags: spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn, apache-beam

I am currently trying to run beam pipeline with windowing and groupbykey over the spark runner.

Locally, it works fully,

but in yarn mode, it seems to not trigger panes after `GroupByKey.create()` down the stream at all (no final hbase mutations).

All ParDos before grouping successfully log the messages (got from kafka).

Windowing strategy with default trigger:

```
Window.<String>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(WINDOW_SIZE_MIN)))
```

I also tried triggering in processing time.

Does anybody have any insight on current support for that in spark runner 2.0.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently a bug in 2.0.0 with watermark based triggers in Spark runner in cluster mode which causes them never to trigger. It should be fixed in 2.0.1 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2359